# How to get "ACCESS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES" scope for developing application on jira

Tags: jira-plugin

I am developing a jira application that needs "ACCESS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES" permission. As per the GDPR guidelines, one can not access email addresses of users without getting explicit permission from user or from the jira admin on user's behalf.
The app descriptor defined:

```
  "key": "*****",
  "baseUrl": "https://****.ngrok.io/",
  "name": "Cloudapp",
  "authentication": {
    "type": "jwt"
  },
  "lifecycle": {
    "installed": "/installed",
    "uninstalled": "/uninstalled"
  },
  "scopes": [
    "READ",
    "ACCESS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES"
  ]
}
```

On installing this application via "Upload app" option(as seen in image below), I receive the following error:
`Installation failed. The app specifies the ACCESS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES scope, but it is not currently approved for such access.`

[Jira Manage apps page - error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCYaH.png)

There are guidelines to get this permissions for listing your application on marketplace: [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=xMXHX-ycLMKG4-EPkvScmAQ&q=access_email_address%20for%20developer%20mode%20%20application%20on%20jira&oq=access_email_address%20for%20developer%20mode%20%20application%20on%20jira&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCAAQRxCwA1CGiAtYlMULYNLXC2gGcAB4BIAB2QSIAZ1GkgEMMC42LjE5LjYuMS4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjsjtTL4K_tAhVCwzgGHRI6B0MQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)
But I would like to have access to email address while the development process of my application(and not when I am trying to list it on marketplace). Is there any way to get such permission for development purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to request access, and must complete a few steps before you do (like providing a privacy policy.

Here are all the details: https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/guidelines-for-requesting-access-to-email-address/27603